# Change existing loaded jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using wordpress and divi theme. I want to change the jump to anchor animation speed that is managed through the js /wp-content/themes/Divi/js/custom.js with this code at line 1117

```
$( 'a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])' ).click( function() {
            var $this_link = $( this ),
                has_closest_smooth_scroll_disabled = $this_link.closest( '.et_smooth_scroll_disabled' ).length,
                has_closest_woocommerce_tabs = ( $this_link.closest( '.woocommerce-tabs' ).length && $this_link.closest( '.tabs' ).length ),
                has_closest_timetable_tab = $this_link.closest( '.tt_tabs_navigation' ).length,
                has_closest_eab_cal_link = $this_link.closest( '.eab-shortcode_calendar-navigation-link' ).length,
                has_closest_ee_cart_link = $this_link.closest( '.view-cart-lnk' ).length,
                has_acomment_reply = $this_link.hasClass( 'acomment-reply' ),
                is_woocommerce_review_link = $this_link.hasClass( 'woocommerce-review-link' ),
                disable_scroll = has_closest_smooth_scroll_disabled || has_closest_ee_cart_link || has_closest_woocommerce_tabs || has_closest_eab_cal_link || has_acomment_reply || is_woocommerce_review_link || has_closest_timetable_tab;

            if ( ( location.pathname.replace( /^\//,'' ) == this.pathname.replace( /^\//,'' ) && location.hostname == this.hostname ) && ! disable_scroll ) {
                var target = $( this.hash );
                target = target.length ? target : $( '[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']' );
                if ( target.length ) {

                    // automatically close fullscreen menu if clicked from there
                    if ( $this_link.closest( '.et_pb_fullscreen_menu_opened' ).length > 0 ) {
                        et_pb_toggle_fullscreen_menu();
                    }

                    setTimeout(function() {
                        et_pb_smooth_scroll( target, false, 800 );
                    }, 0);

                    if ( ! $( '#main-header' ).hasClass( 'et-fixed-header' ) && $( 'body' ).hasClass( 'et_fixed_nav' ) && $( window ).width() > 980 ) {
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            et_pb_smooth_scroll( target, false, 40, 'linear' );
                        }, 780 );
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

I just want to ask is there a way to change

```
  et_pb_smooth_scroll( target, false, 800 );
```

to

```
 et_pb_smooth_scroll( target, false, 1500 );
```

without changing the original custom.js so I will not loose this modification after any theme update 
but also because I would like to apply this change only to some pages

Comment: Replace third parameter in et_pb_smooth_scroll function to a variable. So you may change the value of that variable whenever you need!

Comment: I cannot do this cause if the theme will update, I will loose the modification cause it will overwrite the existing js, anyway I found a solution with $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').off('click');

Answer (score 0):

found solution, simply using .off() to remove the event handler in a document ready script placed into the wanted pages like this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
//removing the original custom.js click event
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').off('click');

//new click anchor click event
$( 'a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])' ).click( function() {
            var $this_link = $( this ),
                has_closest_smooth_scroll_disabled = $this_link.closest( '.et_smooth_scroll_disabled' ).length,
                has_closest_woocommerce_tabs = ( $this_link.closest( '.woocommerce-tabs' ).length && $this_link.closest( '.tabs' ).length ),
                has_closest_timetable_tab = $this_link.closest( '.tt_tabs_navigation' ).length,
                has_closest_eab_cal_link = $this_link.closest( '.eab-shortcode_calendar-navigation-link' ).length,
                has_closest_ee_cart_link = $this_link.closest( '.view-cart-lnk' ).length,
                has_acomment_reply = $this_link.hasClass( 'acomment-reply' ),
                is_woocommerce_review_link = $this_link.hasClass( 'woocommerce-review-link' ),
                disable_scroll = has_closest_smooth_scroll_disabled || has_closest_ee_cart_link || has_closest_woocommerce_tabs || has_closest_eab_cal_link || has_acomment_reply || is_woocommerce_review_link || has_closest_timetable_tab;

            if ( ( location.pathname.replace( /^\//,'' ) == this.pathname.replace( /^\//,'' ) && location.hostname == this.hostname ) && ! disable_scroll ) {
                var target = $( this.hash );
                target = target.length ? target : $( '[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']' );
                if ( target.length ) {

                    // automatically close fullscreen menu if clicked from there
                    if ( $this_link.closest( '.et_pb_fullscreen_menu_opened' ).length > 0 ) {
                        et_pb_toggle_fullscreen_menu();
                    }

                    setTimeout(function() {
                        et_pb_smooth_scroll( target, false, 1500 );
                    }, 0);

                    if ( ! $( '#main-header' ).hasClass( 'et-fixed-header' ) && $( 'body' ).hasClass( 'et_fixed_nav' ) && $( window ).width() > 980 ) {
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            et_pb_smooth_scroll( target, false, 40, 'linear' );
                        }, 780 );
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
});
```